# Docker Container on App Service failing with "Failed to initialize AppInsights IPA volume" error

Tags: azure, docker, azure-appservice, appinsights

A Docker container is being deployed to an app service, and was happily working for months until we recently tried to deploy to production.  The container was successfully deployed to the ACR, gets pulled down but then fails immedietly and the error message shown is:

`Failed to initialize AppInsights IPA volume`

The only way we can get the container to run again is to disable application insights.  Our dockerfile doesn't define any volumes, we are not using docker compose, the container deploys to all other environments fine, but as soon as the app insights configuration settings are detected its failing whilst trying to initalise a volume no one has defined anywhere.